# Excel VBA. Matching the BackColor of a TextBox to the .Interior.Color of a cell

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, backcolor

I can't seem to find an answer for this.  I have a spreadsheet with a userform, and I'm trying to match the back colour of TextBox47 with the corresponding cell on the sheet, the value of which is fetched via a Listbox.  What I need is to be able to click on the list item, and the text box to fill with that colour.

I have the following code to colour the cells in the sheet, according to date, and with named ranges for parameters.. and this runs on UserForm Initialise()

```
Dim cell As Range
      With Range("data_table[Date Test]")
    
     
    For Each cell In Range("data_table[Date Test]")
        If cell.Value < Range("Today") Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            ElseIf cell.Value >= Range("Today") And cell.Value <= Range("Thirty_Days") Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf cell.Value > Range("Thirty_Days") And cell.Value <= Range("Sixty_Days") Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
            ElseIf cell.Value > Range("Sixty_Days") And cell.Value <= Range("Ninety_Days") Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 43
            ElseIf cell.Value > Range("Ninety_Days") Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 18

         End If

    Next cell
    End With
```

This works fine, I then tried the following to colour the textbox

```
 Private Sub TextBox47_Change()
    Me.TextBox47.Text = Format(TextBox47.Text, "dd/mmm/yyyy")
    Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("data_table[Date Test]")
          With Range("data_table[Date Test]")
    Me.TextBox47.BackColor = .Interior.Color
        Next cell
    
    End With
```

I think I need to add the following somewhere..

```
TextBox47.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 65)
```

Which is the ListBox reference for the TextBox.. but I'm starting to get very confused now.  I've been looking at this for a couple of days.

---

Edit to add Listbox code as asked.

```
    Private Sub ComboBox8_Change()

Dim i As Long

Me.ListBox1.Clear
For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("A:A"))
If Sheet1.Cells(i, 10).Value = Me.ComboBox8.Value Then

Me.ListBox1.AddItem Sheet1.Cells(i, 10).Value
'ID Number
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 0) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
'Title
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
```

So would it be more something like this..

```
 Private Sub TextBox47_Change()
    Me.TextBox47.Text = Format(TextBox47.Text, "dd/mmm/yyyy")
Me.TextBox47.BackColor = .Interior.Color
    End Sub
```

Which gives a Compile Error

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3379.png)

Newer code

I've now changed it to this..

```
Private Sub TextBox47_Change()
    Dim cell As Range
        Me.TextBox47.Text = Format(TextBox47.Text, "dd/mmm/yyyy")
            With Range("data_table[Date Test]")
                Me.TextBox47.BackColor = Range("data_table[Date Test]").Interior.Color
            End With
End Sub
```

Which at least doesn't throw up an error, but on every selection the BackColor is black.  I started with ..

```
Private Sub TextBox47_Change()
        Dim cell As Range
            Me.TextBox47.Text = Format(TextBox47.Text, "dd/mmm/yyyy")
                With Range("data_table[Date Test]")
                    Me.TextBox47.BackColor = Range("cell").Interior.Color
                End With
    End Sub
```

But that just stopped at a Run Time error 1004

Yet another edit.. please tell me if continual adding to this post is the wrong way to do it.

[image]

This, when hovering over is actually picking up the correct info from the cell that I'm after (I've tried different ones to make sure), in the Listbox selection that I'm clicking on, so I guess now it's a case of telling the Interior.Colour to look at the cell that is chosen?

Comment: How are the cell's value and the listbox related?

Comment: @SJR Edited.. I did have it there at some point.. just lots of brain freeze.. sorry.  It now turns the Textbox backcolor black

Comment: Probably it should be `With cell` but don't understand why you are looping through a range as the textbox colour will only use the last value in the loop. The code as posted won't work anyway as the `end with` needs to be inside the loop.

Comment: The listbox shows 6 columns of a sheet running A - BQ "Private Sub ComboBox8_Change()

Dim i As Long

Me.ListBox1.Clear
For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("A:A"))
If Sheet1.Cells(i, 10).Value = Me.ComboBox8.Value Then

Me.ListBox1.AddItem Sheet1.Cells(i, 10).Value
'ID Number
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 0) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
'Title
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value" etc..

Comment: Sorry, couldn't work out how to put code in a comment box

Comment: I've changed the code, removing the loop, and added the new code to an edit above, along with the error box that comes with it.  :(

Comment: That dot is only valid inside a `With` clause as it must be linked to something (in this case a range).

Comment: added updated code to post.  Thanks for your help so far..  :)

Comment: Not sure I'm helping. Bit hard to follow this as the code seems to be randomly changed and the question is now rather confusing with so many bits of code. With the last snippet you would a range named "Cell".

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying to update the code each time you suggest something new.  It's only (I think) my second post on this forum, so I'm probably doing it all wrong.. apologies.  I've now changed the range to the listbox range for that textbox, see image 2 (which dissapeared, leaving only the link??) and that at least now is picking up the information from the correct cell in (in this case column 65) from the listbox selection.  Just a case of getting the interior colour from that Listbox entry cell reference..  I think?

Again, apologies if this isn't how it should be done..

Comment: So the listbox returns a date so how does that relate to a cell?

Comment: That date is the information in the cell, and it sees the correct date for each selection I've tried, so the address of the cell is identified correctly now, I just need to get the Interior.Color of the cell to show as the BackColor of the TextBox.. do I need to somehow identify the cell address from that first, and then use the cell address to get the color?  As you can see I'm way past my current understanding..  :)

Comment: So you have a listbox which returns a date. A cell also contains that date. You want a textbox to be coloured the same as that cell. Is that the basic scenario?  Btw I can't see where you identify the address of the cell.

Comment: The listbox pulls the date from the sheet, although that column isn't visible in the listbox, it populates a report sheet on another page.  The date is in a column of cells on the sheet all containing a date, the cells of which are coloured using the date ranges in the first snippet.
I assumed that the address was known to the code as when hovering over the ListBox range (as in Pic 2) it knew what the information in the cell was, so must have the address in the background somewhere in order to do that each time

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work.. although not sure if it's the most elegant solution.  :)

To save confusing it with the code above, which has gotten a bit disjointed and messy, here's all the new working code and the explanation I came up with

Code to colour cells in sheet:

```
Dim cell As Range
  
      For Each cell In Range("data_table[Date Reviewed]")
        If cell.Value < Range("Today") Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 7  'Magenta
            ElseIf cell.Value >= Range("Today") And cell.Value <= Range("Thirty_Days") Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3  'Red
            ElseIf cell.Value > Range("Thirty_Days") And cell.Value <= Range("Sixty_Days") Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 45  'Orange
            ElseIf cell.Value > Range("Sixty_Days") And cell.Value <= Range("Ninety_Days") Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4  'Green
            ElseIf cell.Value > Range("Ninety_Days") Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 19  'Beige
        End If

    Next cell
```

This is in `UserForm_Initialize()`

And then to match the cell colour with `TextBox.BackColor`, I've used the `ListBox.ListIndex` to get the date, using the following code:

```
Private Sub TextBox47_Change()

      Me.TextBox47.Text = Format(TextBox47.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")
      
                    If (Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 65)) < Range("Today") Then
                     TextBox47.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 255)  'Magenta
                ElseIf (Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 65)) >= Range("Today") And (Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 65)) <= Range("Thirty_Days") Then
                     TextBox47.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)  'Red
                ElseIf (Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 65)) > Range("Thirty_Days") And (Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 65)) <= Range("Sixty_Days") Then
                     TextBox47.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 0)  'Orange
                ElseIf (Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 65)) > Range("Sixty_Days") And (Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 65)) <= Range("Ninety_Days") Then
                     TextBox47.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)  'Green
                ElseIf (Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 65)) > Range("Ninety_Days") Then
                     TextBox47.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 204)  'Beige
        End If
        
     End Sub
```

I can now call that `TextBox.BackColor` to set the associated `Interior.Color` of any other cell I'm forwarding on that value to, such as the Report I'm generating in Sheet2:

```
Sheet2.Range("D105").Value = Me.TextBox47.Text
Sheet2.Range("D105").Interior.Color = Me.TextBox47.BackColor
```

Thankyou for your help and patience.  It was your comment "So you have a listbox which returns a date" which helped me to see where I was actually getting the date from when hovering over the line of code, rather than it seeing a particular `Cell.Address`, and hence how I got the above to work.

Again, thankyou, and I hope I didn't break too many posting rules in the meantime.  :)

Apologies, but I couldn't see a thanks button anywhere.

Cheers

Liam